# Properly disposing of variable. Are using statements enough?

Tags: c#, ado.net, using, idisposable

I have a class that contains methods that calls stored procedures. Some of these stored procedures return data structures others do not. Here is an example of one of the methods.

```
public DataTable GetProductData(int productID)
{
  DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
  using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
  {
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTIONSTRING"))
    {
      using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("getProductData", sqlConn))
      {
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", productID);
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
      }
    }
  }
  return dataTable;
}
```

This method is used by another program when data access is required. Here is an example of a method that makes use of the above method ...

```
public DataTable GetProductInfoFromDatabase(int productID)
{
  DataLibrary dl = new DataLibrary();
  return dl.GetProductData(productID);
}
```

What I am wondering is how I should dispose of the `dl` variable once I have retrieved the data. Will the garbage collection take care of it or should I implement IDisposable in the class where the `GetProductData` method is defined? Are the `using` statements enough?

Comment: That method should probably be static.

Comment: There is never a reason to write an empty `Dispose()` method.

Comment: @SLaks: Even a `virtual` empty `Dispose()` method?  What about empty virtual `Dispose(bool)` ?

Comment: There is nothing to Dispose().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your class is holding onto *unmanaged* resources or otherwise `IDisposable` objects; **no**, you do not need to implement `IDisposable` yourself. An empty `Dispose` method buys you *nothing*.

In the code you provided, the `using` statements are sufficient. The `DataLibrary` object created in `GetProductInfoFromDatabase` will be collected by the GC as you expect.

Comment: Unless the class is modified later such that it needs `IDisposable` or to `Dispose` of certain resources after it has already been previously implemented. (Of course, one could argue that this could represent a programme-breaking change, and should result in a new class.)